Why do far objects on a mirror require a different focus despite its image being closeup?
Apologies if this question is already answered - I am not sure what this phenomenon is called so have not been able to search this topic thoroughly.
Say on a laptop screen, you have content displaying from the laptop itself - and then you also see the screen reflecting what is behind you at the same time.

Example:

Conceptually, it makes sense that far objects and close objects require different focus.

But isn't the light that is coming from the laptop screen and the light that's reflecting off of the screen (whatever is behind me) - both be from the same distance from my eyes? (i.e both images are the same distance from my eyes)
Why can't my eyes focus on both images clearly? When I focus on one, the other become out-of-focus.

To take a guess, I'm wondering if distance from object isn't the only thing that affects focus?

On a tangent, but similar thought - if one is near-sighted, would the laptop screen content be clear but the reflection image be blurry because the objects that it's reflecting is further away? Similar concept as both 'images' are coming from the laptop screen - just that one is a reflection

I'm not sure the way you use the words "I focus on [X]" can be easily given a physically precise meaning. Even if you hold a pencil in your hand and focus on it, you'll feel as if your hand that's holding the pencil is a bit less focused. I believe it is at least partially related to a neurological process that is part of "human vision", and not merely just an optical effect.

Also see related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/686298/

Your eyes focus based on how the distance to an object affects the angle of light rays. There is a misconception that mirrors act like camera screens and become the new source, but this is not how it works. As shown by the image below, the angles of the light rays continue to change after hitting the mirror in the same way that they would if they went right through, apart from the fact that they are reflected.


"But isn't the light that is coming from the laptop screen and the light that's reflecting off of the screen (whatever is behind me) - both be from the same distance from my eyes? "
For a plane mirror, the image is virtual, that is, the rays of light are such that the image appears to come from a distance behind the mirror and the distance behind the mirror is equal to the distance of the subject in front of the mirror. When viewing the writing on the screen, the subject is on the screen so much closer to you and therefore requires your eyes to focus at a different distance. So while the light in both cases is coming off of the screen, the distance that you have to focus in both cases is not the same.

Your eyeball bends light rays from an object down to a point when you are focused on an object.  By adjusting the shape of your cornea, you adjust the amount that you bend the light rays.  Light from objects typically emanates in all directions, which means that for objects that are nearby they are hitting your eyeball over a wide range of angles, and so you are required to bend the light rays more in order to focus them down to a point.  On the other hand, light rays from far away objects hit your eyeball at nearly the same angle, and so you don't have to bend them as much.  When you are focusing on your screen, the light from each pixel of your screen is hitting your eyeball over a large range of angles.  When you are focusing on objects reflecting off your screen, the light from objects is bouncing off the screen and then hitting your eyeballs, and the resulting light rays range over a much smaller range of angles (because they all bounce at nearly the same angle; they are not scattered by your screen), and so your cornea must set itself to a different shape in order to bend the light less than when you are focused on the screen.
